# C++ / CLI MDI container

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mdi

Parent form is a MDI container, i open a new form called newMDIChild and set that form to be a child of a form Parent. how can i in form FirstMDIChild open a new form SecondMDIChild  and set that form for  a child of form Parent and close the FirstMDIChild, ? I need to use pointers, can somebody explain how to do that. Ty

```
Parent(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FirstPage^ newMDIChild = gcnew FirstPage();
        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newMDIChild->MdiParent = this;
        newMDIChild->MaximizeBox = false;
        // Display the new form.
        newMDIChild->Show();

    }
```

Comment: Well, exact same code.  But instead of `this` you'll have to use `this->MdiParent` to assign the property.  The usual struggle with C++/CLI is to get the #includes correct.  Tends to be easier to understand if you just let the FirstPage class fire an event so the parent can create the new child window.  Just guessing, you did not explain why you have trouble implementing this.

Comment: The problem is that the secondchild is opening in a new form.

Comment: Hard to make sense of those comments.  MDI is a windowing model where child windows overlap each other by design.  There can be only one parent.  It dates back to the 1990s when users had monitors no bigger than 800x600 so overlapping was pretty necessary.  On modern hardware you'd consider a docking layout, similar to the way VS works.  Dockpanel Suite is a popular library.

Comment: I mean opening in  a new form..but not in the parent form.. where i want it..

Comment: all i want is when i close firstchild and open the second. i want that second in the same parent form.. and when i write this->MdiParent i dont get that..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve